# Selection subquery using another table in database ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I need to 'extract' a list of variables based on the IDs from another table. Using a subquery seems to be the best method. I have a large list of variables and have outside calculated a second list. This second list does not have coordinate data attached to it, so I need to select the same values in the original list to pull the data out. The shapefile and table are both in the catalog.

I try to do a simple select by attribute. It gives me the

```
SELECT * FROM US_Maize_All WHERE: "pointid" = (SELECT "pointid" FROM Maize_Table)
```

but this only gives me a SQL expression error. The "pointid" parameters are selected from the option box. As far as I can tell this is the exact format as any other info I can find online. Has to be something I'm overlooking why this will not work.

Comment: if you use equality sign in where clause,subquery must return only one record and your query may return more than one value.Try this query I hope it works: Select * From US_Maize_All Where pointid IN (Select pointId from Maize_Table) and I think also fields name must not be in "" because they interpreted as fixed values.So I did not use "" for pointid field name.

Comment: I had tried the IN already but no dice. I took out the " ", but Arc put them in there to start with. This is just in the standard dialog box, not in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Nested or subqueries in ArcGIS are only available when using geodatabase formats, per the help files - bottom of [this one](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002t000000) which also links to [this more detailed one](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/) about halfway down the page.

> Coverages, shapefiles, and other nongeodatabase file-based data
>   sources do not support subqueries. Subqueries that are performed on
>   versioned ArcSDE feature classes and tables will not return features
>   that are stored in the delta tables. File geodatabases provide the
>   limited support for subqueries explained in this section, while
>   personal and ArcSDE geodatabases provide full support. For information
>   on the full set of subquery capabilities of personal and ArcSDE
>   geodatabases, refer to your DBMS documentation.

If you convert your shapefile to a geodatabase feature class and bring the table into the geodatabase as well, you should be able to use the desired query. I believe the syntax for the dialog would be:

`"pointid" IN (SELECT "pointid" FROM Maize_Table)`

Some syntax examples are given in the above linked help files. The same restriction applies to Python, but they syntax may differ.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert everything to a geodatabase, maybe you could try to just join them in arc, with pointid as the join field.